# How can I "reset" my CRT monitor?

Tags: display, reset, crt

I have a clunky old CRT monitor as my main monitor (iiyama make) that I've messed around with previously - the screen is slanted, curved and has a "zoom effect" that makes things get thinner toward the edges. This is all due to my tinkering but I've never been able to get it back to normal.

I was wondering if there's:

- A standard reset button for CRTs (I've never found one)
- A guide to configuring it to display properly.

Of course I want to ditch it for another LCD but I'm stuck with it at the moment :)

**Update:** The monitor is an Iiyama 19" LS902UT Vision Master 1451. There is a recall option in the OSD but that only resets colour/brightness/contrast, and not the pincushion/rotate settings which are wrong. I've tried by hand to adjust these but I'm not getting too far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for a reset/restore option in the menu. It is a standard option and it should be present in even fairly old monitors.

If there is no option, try this sequence to manually correct the issue.

1. Degauss the monitor.
2. Use the offset controls (up/down, left/right) to center the image.
3. Use the size controls to expand/contract it.

If you cannot center the image, you may have to take the monitor to a service center to get the aiming coils realigned.

Providing the exact model of your monitor can help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard reset button. You need to check the manual, or search online for the key sequence (generally, holding one or more buttons for some specified interval)

Comment: I haven't had any luck finding even a reference to it online but I'll try holding down buttons, there's only 4 :P

Answer (score 1):

Is there no "reset to factory default" in the on-screen menus? That is what I would look for.

Comment: There's a recall but it just affects the colours.

Comment: Then I suggest you go with Abhinavs answer and try to locate the manual or even call their support, sometimes they have an old technician who happens to remember these things.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an option in the menu to do that. Just look for it and you will find it.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a reset settings option somewhere in the monitor menu. It may be worth going through each menu and sub-menu until you find it.

If you still can't find it, posting the model number may allow people to search for it

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to play around with the display controls to get it back. There isn't any kind of reset button on CRT monitors because the display is controlled by the physical knobs.